# How to handle possible params on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I'm doing an API for my app.

Currently, you can call `api/v1/clients` and get the Clients JSON back, as expected. You can also do `api/v1/clients?client_id=1` and get the JSON representation of the Client object with `id` 1.

Here's my `API::V1::ClientsController`:

```
class API::V1::ClientsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:client_id]
      @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
      render template: 'api/v1/clients/show'
    else
      @clients = Client.all
    end
  end

end
```

I want that if, for example, you have a typo on the endpoint (`api/v1/clients?clent_id=1`), the app returns a JSON object with an error:

```
{
  error: {
    error_code: 10,
    error_description: "Bad endpoint"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to, say, make a `switch` statement on the params to handle the possible cases?

Comment: "Handling params" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Make a *private method* in your controller, this one will check your `params`:

- If `params` is empty it returns `false`
- If `params` contains `'client_id'` and its value is a numeric it returns the value
- Otherwise it raises an exception.

Then in you *action method* you use this result:

- If the result is `false` you display all results
- Otherwise it display the record based on the id returned by your private method

As for the exception: you use a `rescue_from` to display the "Bad endpoint" JSON response